# How to write data to both MongoDB and Redis but only read from Redis with Sails.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, redis, sails.js, scalability

I am creating an app that uses sails.js as backend and was thinking of using this data storing/retrieving method:
- The data is saved in both Redis and Mongo DB
- The data is only read from Redis
- When the server restarts/resets the data from the MongoDB is written into Redis so at any point in time the two databases are actually the same.

In this scenario I'm having both persistence and speed.

Here are my questions:
- Is it a good idea? I understand the implications of using both the RAM and HDD for the same thing.
- Can this be easily attained in Sails? Write to two, read from one?
- Would this work for a high scalability solution for a game like QuizUp? (Let's say 10 million users). In this scenario my scalability solution would be deploy the app to Heroku/Beanstalk/Azure and auto-scale the computing power and have the Mongo DB and Redis clusters on different computers.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?